# Realmente é necessário o "Then" no final do bloco If?

Tags: .net, vb.net, if

O Compilador do Visual Basic .NET parece ignorar a palavra reservada `Then`, a que fica no final do bloco `If`.

```
 If (1 + 1 = 2) Then
      Console.WriteLine("Passou no teste.")
 End If
```

E agora, sem o `Then`:

```
 If (1 + 1 = 2)
      Console.WriteLine("Também passou no teste.")
 End If
```

Esse foi o resultado no Console:

> `Passou no teste.`
>
> `Também passou no teste.`

A Keyword **Then** é realmente necessária no Visual Basic .NET? Ela tem uma função especial ou é algum tipo de "Melhora a leitura de código"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ele é obrigatório apenas quando vai usar comandos em uma linha, assim ele é o separador. Quando vai executar um bloco de comandos ele é **opcional** mesmo.

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/if-then-else-statement?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Exemplo de *single line*:

```
If x > 0 Then y = 0
```

Ou mais de um comando em uma linha:

```
If x > 0 Then y = 0 : z = 0
```

Bloco de código:

```
If x > 0
    y = 0
    z = 0
End If
```

Também funciona igual:

```
If x > 0 Then
    y = 0
    z = 0
End If
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/Then.vb).